# How to test a method that depends on another already tested method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm working on a method that can be considered a specialization of another already defined and tested method. Here's an example code to illustrate:

```
public class ProductService {

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        //do something
    }

    public void addSpecialProduct(Product product) {
        addProduct(product);
        //do something after
    }

}
```

I don't want to copy the tests I have for `addProduct` which are already pretty complex. What I want is when I define the tests for `addSpecialProduct`, I just make sure that it also calls `addProduct` in the process. If this were a matter of 2 classes collaborating, it's easy to have the collaborator mocked and just verify that the target method gets called (and stub it if necessary). However, the 2 methods belong to the same class.

What I'm thinking right now is to spy on the object I'm testing, something like:

```
public void testAddSpecialProduct() {
    //set up code
    ProductService service = spy(new DefaultProductService());    
    service.addSpecialProduct(specialProduct);
    verify(service).addProduct(specialProduct);
    //more tests
}
```

However, I'm wondering whether this approach somehow defeats the purpose of unit testing. What's the general consensus on this matter?

Comment: Could you put your assertions for the `addProduct` method in a test utility method and reuse that between multiple test cases?

Comment: this class sounds bit code smell to me, it would be better idea to compose these 2 functionality (product and special product) into 2 separate classes(then your test becomes obvious and easy).  have generic 'add' and 'specialized add' defeats single responsibility.

Comment: @chrylis that actually sounds reasonable, yes. I've forgotten I did similar things before.

Comment: @kuhajeyan Not really. Imagine this: `addProduct` is basically a straightforward service of adding a product. `addSpecialProduct` is a service that adds a product and then does some other things like, say trigger alerts/notifications, etc.

Comment: Do all of the cases that you've tested in `addProduct` also apply to `addSpecialProduct`, or just a subset of them?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how rigorous you want to be with your unit testing. In the extreme sense, unit testing should only test the behavior, not the implementation. This would mean you would need to duplicate your tests (or take take @chrylis' suggestion of abstracting out common functionality to helpers). Ensuring the other method is called is testing the implementation.

However in reality, I think your idea of spying on the instance to ensure the other well-tested method is called is a good idea. Here are my reasons:

1) It simplifies your code.

2) It becomes immediately clear to me what is happening. It says to me that everything that has been tested for the other method will now also be true, and here are the extra assertions.

One day you may modify the implementation so that the other method is not called, and this will cause your unit tests to fail, which is what people are generally trying to avoid by not testing the implementation. But in my experience, changes like this are much more common when the behavior is going to change anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider refactoring your code. Use the strategy pattern to to actually implement the functionality for adding products and special products.

```
public class ProductService {

    @Resource
    private AddProductStrategy normalAddProductStrategy;
    @Resource
    private AddProductStrategy addSpecialProductStrategy;

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        normalAddProductStrategy.addProduct(product);
    }

    public void addSpecialProduct(Product product) {
        addSpecialProductStrategy.addProduct(product);
    }
}
```

There will be 2 Implementations of the `AddProductStrategy`. One does that what happend in your original `ProductService.addProduct` implementation. The second implementation will delegate to the first one and then do the additional work required. Therefore you can test each strategy separately. The second strategy implementation is then just a decorator for the first implementation.